# Adding a single row with "empty" entries to a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame that I want to add rows to.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Name', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'])
```

I can add a row to this data frame with the following code:

```
df.loc[len(df)]= [2.0, 'James', 97, 96, 87]
```

However it is possible that a row will not have an entry in either the 'Value1' or 'Value3' column.  I have tried the following code:

```
df.loc[len(df)]= [2.0, 'James', , 96, 87]
```

but this throws errors.  Is there a way to tell Pandas that the particular column of the row should be empty?

Comment: You mean `NaN`? `df.loc[len(df)]= [2.0, 'James',NaN, 96, 87]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Just for anyone else it is `numpy.nan` that produces NaN.

Comment: Depends on your version of pandas I think whether you need to specify `np.NaN` or just plain `NaN`